# How to iterate models in zk over even index?

Tags: zk, zk-grid

I need to display objects in a model row-wise, with two models in each row. In my zul file I have to group the models in groups of two. How is it possible using foreach, foreachstatus or template ?
I am using zk grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example witch switch between 2 templates on the index.
You just have to implement the modulo 2 and check for 1 or 0.

http://www.zkfiddle.org/sample/2rjaqos/4-MVVM-with-nested-template

zul code of that link :

```
<listbox model="@load(vm.beans)">
        <listhead children="@load(vm.colTitle)">
            <template name="children" var="title">
                <listheader label="@load(title)" />
            </template>
        </listhead>
        <template name="model" var="bean">
            <listitem children="@load(vm.colTitle)  @template(forEachStatus.index lt 1 ? 'fixed' : 'variable')">
                <template name="fixed">
                    <listcell label="@load(bean.title)" />
                </template>
                <template name="variable">
                    <listcell>
                        <checkbox checked="@load(bean.states[forEachStatus.index - 1])"
                            label="@load(bean.states[forEachStatus.index - 1] ? 'true' : 'false')"
                            onCheck="@command('onCheckState', bean=bean, state=self.isChecked(), index=forEachStatus.index - 1)" />
                    </listcell>
                </template>
            </listitem>
        </template>
</listbox>
```

here another example with the modulo but with 1 template :
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2pmngjk/9-Listbox-with-Template

Zul code of second example :

```
<zk>
  <window apply="pkg$.FruitProvider">
          <listbox model="${$composer.fruits}">
                  <template name="model">
                          <listitem>
                                  <listcell if="${forEachStatus.index % 2 == 0}">
                                          <textbox value="${each[0]}" />
                                          <textbox value="${each[1]}" />
                                  </listcell>
                                  <listcell unless="${forEachStatus.index % 2 == 0}">
                                          <label value="${each[0]}" />
                                          <label value="${each[1]}" />
                                  </listcell>
                          </listitem>
                  </template>
          </listbox>
  </window>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 0):

Greets,
AFAIK you can apply only 1 model to your grid..of course you can manipulate it on the controller side
However, if you want to know the element index of your iteration with the template component,
use @load( **varName** Status.index)
example:

```
<template name="model" var="element">
```

then inside the template:

```
<label value="@load(elementStatus.index)" />
```

and it'll output the position of the element inside the model

more infos [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Property_Binding#Iteration_Variable)